# On badges view add option to sort by "number of users" awarded

Tags: feature-request, badges

On the pages https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general and https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags it will be good to add an option  to sort by "number of users" awarded.

Comment: Why?  This seems like a feature request just for the sake of a feature request.

Comment: I confess I occasionally look to see how rare a badge I've just acquired is. This would make it easier, and also highlight a badge that lots of people have and I don't.

Comment: It will be easy to understand how easy (or hard) is to achieve each badge. The current page shows number of users anyway, but alphabetical order doesn't give any value.

Comment: For tag badges, this gives an impression of the popularity of a tag.